# Store config files and examples in githup repo

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on github that is called my-configs. In this I store different vim files and other config files and examples I want to have available wherever I am. Now what I'm trying  to do is push just a single file or folder up to this repository without having to commit the whole local repo.

For example: I have a project that is called Project1, this is a local git repo with two files file1.conf and file2.rand. Now I want to maintain this as a local repo but I also want to push the file file1.cong to a already existing github account. 
Later I start a new project called Project2 and have a folder called grunt/ and once again I only want to push this folder to github and working with the rest of the project locally.

The github repo would be a collection of files and folders from many other existing projects.

Comment: Why not use Dropbox or something like that?

Comment: Yes that would work, I just wanted to have everything coding related on github.

Comment: Would it be viable to add your `my-configs` repo as a remote and check out its master branch (which would clean the working directory of everything tracked by the branch you were on before). Commit you configs, push them and switch back to your development branch?